# Question regarding homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $(X,d)$ and $(Y,D)$ are two metric spaces and let $f$ be a homeomorphism between the two metric spaces. Define a new metric $p$ on $X$ defined by $p(x,y) = D(f(x),f(y))$.Then is it true that $d$ and $p$ are equivalent metrics on $X$?

Answer (score 2):

They need not be Lipschitz-equivalent, as can be seen by taking $(Y,D) = (X, d/(1+d))$ and $f = {\rm Id}_X$ (as long as $d$ is not bounded). But it appears that $d$ and $p$ will always generate the same topology.

Note that for all $x \in X$ and $r>0$ we have $B_p(x,r) = f^{-1}(B_D(f(x),r))$.

Fix $x \in X$ and $r> 0$. We want $r' > 0$ such that $B_p(x,r')\subseteq B_d(x,r)$, right? Since homeomorphisms are open mappings, $f(B_d(x,r))$ is an $D$-open set around $f(x)$, so there is $r' > 0$ such that $B_D(f(x),r')\subseteq f(B_d(x,r))$. This implies that $B_p(x,r') \subseteq B_d(x,r)$, as wanted.

For the other direction, fix $x \in X$ and $r>0$. This time we want $r'>0$ such that $B_d(x,r')\subseteq B_p(x,r)$. Note that $B_p(x,r) = f^{-1}(B_D(f(x),r))$ is an $d$-open set around $x$, by continuity of $f$, so we get $r'>0$ such that $B_d(x,r')\subseteq B_p(x,r)$, done.

Comment: They definitely do give the same topology.

Comment: Yeah, if you think categorically then $(X,p) = f^*(Y,D)$ makes it more obvious :)

Comment: can u give a more detailed explanation?

Comment: What did you not understand from the above? It is already quite detailed.

Comment: For example, how do u justify the first two lines of your proof(line 7 and 8)

Comment: I'm using the app on the mobile so I'm not sure lines 7 and 8 are the same for us both. If you mean $B_p(x,r) =f^{-1}(B_D(f(x),r))$, just write up the definition of the right side.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $X=Y=\mathbb R$, and $f(x)=x^{1/3}$. Then the identity map $\mathrm{Id}: (\mathbb R, D) \to (\mathbb R, p)$ is not bilipschitz, so the two metrics are not equivalent (though they give the same topology).

Comment: Giving the same topology is what equivalent means! Or, at least as I learned it; after checking [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics) I see the term is ambiguous.

Comment: As far as I knew, there was a difference between "equivalent metrics" and "Lipschitz-equivalent metrics". See my answer